# Locking/Unlocking merged Excel cells using C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I'm trying to unlock a couple of cells using the code below. The cells are merged with each other and I don't want to disjoin them as I am working on a client's quote template and do not want to change his quote structure :) Anyway...here is the code:

```
Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
ws.Range["F25:F42"].Locked = false; //Error here
```

I get an error saying:

> We can't do that to a merged cell.

Is there a way of getting around this error so that I can unlock/lock the cells as I will?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing this:

```
Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
foreach (Excel.Range ra in ws.Range["F25:F42"]) {
    ra.MergeArea.Locked = false;
}
```